# Why doesn't AudioKit's AKMicrophoneTracker work on a physical iOS device?

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit

When I use AudioKit's `AKMicrophoneTracker` on a physical device, the the frequency and amplitude are always both `0`. But in the playground and in the iOS simulator, it works perfectly.

Here's a rough example:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    let tracker = AKMicrophoneTracker()

    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        // start the tracker and show frequency information
        tracker.start()
        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.1, repeats: true, block: { _ in
            print(tracker.frequency)
            print(tracker.amplitude)
        })
    }

}
```

I've reset my physical device's privacy permissions, and iOS is correctly prompting me to allow microphone access. It still doesn't work even though I'm allowing microphone access.

**How can I get AKMicrophoneTracker to actually read these values?**

I'm using AudioKit 4.0.3. It works as expected when using:

- the AudioKit playground on my Mac
- a simulator iPhone 7 Plus running iOS 11.1

It does not work when using:

- A physical iPhone 7 Plus running iOS 11.1.1 (and also occurs on iOS 11.1)

*I originally posted this as [a bug on AudioKit's GitHub issue tracker](https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/issues/1118). However, Aure (the project maintainer) encouraged me to post here instead.*

Comment: why you have try to track on 0.1 second. i think you should use 1 or 2 minimum second hope will helpful to you

Comment: do you checked in someother device which have iOS 11 or 10

Comment: @Tubelight longer time between samples might give better results, but even a time as long as 0.1 seconds should give me _some_ data, even if it's not accurate. But I'm just getting zeros.

Comment: @R.Mohan I have not checked on a physical iOS 10 device. I unfortunately don't have one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Ercell0's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47585563/5651536) is correct--his code works perfectly. My specific problem appears to have been caused by some other AudioKit functionality which I thought I had disabled during testing. It was equivalent to running:

```
AudioKit.output = AKMixer()
AudioKit.start()
```

after the `AKMicrophoneTracker` initialization. This caused the `AKMicrophoneTracker` problem I was experiencing.

It looks like this *might* be a bug in AudioKit. I've opened [issue #1142](https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/issues/1142) on Github.

Answer (score 6):

The following worked for me on 7+, 6s:

**In AppDelegate:**

```
import UIKit
import AudioKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?
let tracker = AKMicrophoneTracker()



func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    // start the tracker and show frequency information
    tracker.start()
    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.5, repeats: true, block: { _ in
        print(self.tracker.frequency)
        print(self.tracker.amplitude)
    })


    return true
}
...
```

**info.plist**

```
...
<key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
<string>WE need your microfone to contact the aliens</string>
...
```

[image]

Comment: You're totally correct--turns out my problem was caused by some other code that I accidentally didn't disable. I've upvoted your answer and awarded you the bounty, but I've marked my answer below as correct as I think it contains the actual relevant info to the problem.